# How to get Scrubbing to work on UISlider using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming, uislider

So I'm using a rather unique version of audio player and everything works except for track scrubbing. The tracks, it should be noted, are buffered and collected from a website. I thought it might have to do with the observers I'm using. But I don't know if it's that really. I'm able to call the duration of the track and I'm able to get the actual UISlider to animate in conjunction with the track progression. But I can't scrub forward or backward. What ends up happening is I can move the slider but the track's progress doesn't move along with it. Here's what I've got:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

       audio.initialize(config: ["loop": true]) { (playerItem, change) in
           var duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem.duration)
           self.scrubSlider.maximumValue = Float(duration)
       }

        scrubSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "position_knob"), for: .normal)       
}

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        scrubSlider.value = 0.0
        print(audio.seekDuration())
        self.scrubSlider.maximumValue = audio.seekDuration()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.trackAudio), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        print(self.scrubSlider.maximumValue)

    }

@objc func trackAudio() {
          var currentTime = audio.seekCurrentTime()
          print(currentTime)
          scrubSlider.value = currentTime
          var duration = audio.seekDuration()

          let remainingTimeInSeconds = duration - currentTime
          timeElapsedLabel.text = audio.createTimeString(time: currentTime)
          timeRemainingLabel.text = audio.createTimeString(time: remainingTimeInSeconds)



    }

    @IBAction func scrubberValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print("Entro")
        var currentTime = (CMTimeGetSeconds((audio.playerQueue?.currentItem!.currentTime())!))
        currentTime = (Float64)((scrubSlider.value))

    }
```

Here's the observer where I collect the duration:

```
      /**
       Setup observers to monitor playback flow
      */
    private func setupObservers(completion: @escaping (AVPlayerItem, Any) -> ()) {

              // listening for current item change
              self.audioQueueObserver = self.playerQueue?.observe(\.currentItem, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (player, _) in

                  print("media item changed...")
                  print("media number ", self?.playerQueue?.items() as Any, self?.playerQueue?.items().count as Any, self?.playerQueue?.currentItem as Any)
                  // loop here if needed //
                  if self?.audioPlayerConfig["loop"] as! Bool == true && self?.playerQueue?.items().count == 0 && self?.playerQueue?.currentItem == nil {
                      self?.playerQueue?.removeAllItems()
                      self?.playerQueue?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
                      for item:AVPlayerItem in (self?.AVItemPool)! {
                        item.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                          self?.playerQueue?.insert(item, after: nil)
                      }
                      self?.playerQueue?.play()
                  }
              }

              // listening for current item status change
              self.audioQueueStatusObserver = self.playerQueue?.currentItem?.observe(\.status, options:  [.new, .old], changeHandler: { (playerItem, change) in
                  guard let currentItemDuration = self.playerQueue?.currentItem?.duration else { return }
                  if playerItem.status == .readyToPlay {
                      print("current item status is ready")
                      print("media Queue ", self.playerQueue?.items() as Any, self.playerQueue?.items().count as Any)
                      print("item duration ", CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem.duration))
                      print("itemD ", CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItemDuration))
                      print(currentItemDuration)
                      completion(playerItem, change)
                  }
              })
```